# SmartGWT TabSet.removeTab removes the tab and selects the previous one. Workaround?

Tags: select, tabs, smartgwt

I have an issue : Several tabs, one new is opened and after some activity in it, it is closed. The problem is that I also have `TabSelectedHandler`s on every `Tab` and they are executed not only `onTabSelected`, but also upon remove (and this happens to be a problem). When removing the last Tab, the prevoius one is being selected. How to avoid this and do only remove? Here is example of the code:

```
Tab existingTab0 = new Tab("Static tab 0");
existingTab0.setID("0");
existingTab0.addTabSelectedHandler(new TabSelectedHandler () {
    public void onTabSelected(final TabSelectedEvent event) {
        // do stuff 0
    }
});

Tab existingTab1 = new Tab("Static tab 1");
existingTab1.setID("1");
existingTab1.addTabSelectedHandler(new TabSelectedHandler () {
    public void onTabSelected(final TabSelectedEvent event) {
        // do stuff 1
    }
});

Tab dynamicTab = new Tab("Dynamic tab");
dynamicTab.setID("2");
dynamicTab.addTabSelectedHandler(new TabSelectedHandler () {
    public void onTabSelected(final TabSelectedEvent event) {
        // do stuff 2
    }
});

TabSet tabSet = new TabSet();
tabSet.addTab(existingTab0);
tabSet.addTab(existingTab1);
tabSet.addTab(dynamicTab);

// upon a specific case I need to remove dynamicTab
tabSet.removeTab(dynamicTab); // forces onTabSelected method for Static tab 1 to be fired and does stuff 1 and this should NOT happen here
```

Any ideas of a workaround? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `HandlerRegistration` returned by `addTabSelectedHandler` method and use it to remove the handler when you want to get rid of your dynamicTab and before invoking the `removeTab` method.

Comment: Thank you very much, this sounds like a solution. I'll try it, but do you know if I can get the `HandlerRegistration` out of the object `Tab`? The thing is that my code is in several different classes. Otherwise I'll need to store somewhere all the `HandlerRegistration`s and get the correct one before removing a `Tab`. A getter would do just great, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: Just Subclass the Tab class with your own class(YourTab extands Tab....) in which you define your properties for example handlerRegistration with its pair of accessor set() and get().

Comment: Thanks for the great ideas. Unfortunately, it's my mistake, as the problem is actually that the tab just BEFORE the closed one is selected :( I'm sorry about this, I will re-write my question.

Comment: Even though it turned to be a different case than what I first wrote here, I used the same technique as you proposed. I subclassed Tab class, removed the Handler of the previous Tab, removed the current Tab, then added the Handler to the previous Tab again. It works.